# Optimization of selection of semi-random rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I currently have a query that randomly selects a job from a table of jobs:

```
select jobs.job_id
from jobs
where (jobs.type is null)
  and (jobs.project_id = 5)
  and (jobs.status = 'Available')
offset floor(random() * (select count(*) from jobs
                         where (jobs.type is null) and (jobs.project_id = 5)
                           and (jobs.status = 'Available')))
limit 1
```

This has the desired functionality, but is too slow.  I am using Postgres 9.2 so I can't use `TABLESAMPLE`, unfortunately.

On the plus side, I do not need it to be truly random, so I'm thinking I can optimize it by making it slightly less random.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could I suggest an index on `jobs(project_id, status, type)`?  That might speed your query, if it is not already defined on the table.

Comment: I do have an index on it and it does speed it up.  Unfortunately it does not speed it up enough

Comment: "on it".  This is one index with three columns in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, why don't you use

```
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
```

If that is also too slow, you could replace your subquery

```
select count(*) from jobs
   where (jobs.type is null) and (jobs.project_id = 5)
      and (jobs.status = 'Available')
```

with something like

```
SELECT reltuples * <factor> FROM pg_class WHERE oid = <tableoid>
```

where `<tableoid>` is the OID of the `jobs` table and `<factor>` is a number that is slightly bigger than the selectivity of the `WHERE` condition of your subquery.

That will save one sequential scan, with the downside that you occasionally get no result and have to repeat the query.

Is that good enough?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make the query faster though

Comment: I have added a second suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick: store the random value **inside the table** and build a (partial) index on it. (you may want to re-randomise this field from time to time to avoid records to never be picked ;-)

```
-- assumed table definition
CREATE table jobs
        ( job_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , type VARCHAR
        , project_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , status VARCHAR NOT NULL
        -- pre-computed magic random number
        -- , magic DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT random()
        );

-- some data to play with
INSERT INTO jobs(type,project_id,status)
SELECT 'aaa' , gs %10 , 'Omg!'
FROM generate_series(1,10000) gs;
UPDATE jobs SET type = NULL WHERE random() < 0.2;
UPDATE jobs SET status = 'Available'  WHERE random() < 0.2;

-- add a column containing random numbers
ALTER TABLE jobs
    ADD column magic DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT random()
    ;

CREATE INDEX ON jobs(magic)
    -- index is only applied for the conditions you will be searching
    WHERE status = 'Available' AND project_id = 5 AND type IS NULL
    ;

-- make sure statistics are present
VACUUM ANALYZE jobs;

-- EXPLAIN
SELECT j.job_id
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.type is null
  AND j.project_id = 5
  AND j.status = 'Available'
ORDER BY j.magic
LIMIT 1
        ;
```

Something similar can be accomplished by  using a serial with a rather high increment value (some prime number around 3G) instead of random+float.